# How can I quickly turn all objects of a layer to independent layers in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, layers, script

I have a single layer with many objects on it. I would like to get each one of them in a separate layer (in order to run a Processing sketch on them afterwords), how can I achieve it?

From [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35512/how-can-i-quickly-turn-all-objects-of-a-layer-to-independent-layers-in-illustrat) I see that in Illustrator there is "Release to layer" function, but apparently there is not something like this in Inkscape. Maybe a Python script is the solution. I don't know how to implement it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly easy... using this extension: [inx-toolsanim](https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-toolsanim)

Here I have one layer with a few objects (for example):

[image: Objects in Inkscape]

- Go to Extensions > Animation > AnimTools
- In the Groups tab, choose 'Wrap each selected object in group':

[image: AmimTools: Groups]

Which does as it says:

[image: Objects to groups]

- Back in the AnimTools panel, now under the Layers tab choose 'Convert each selected group to layer':

[image: AnimTools panel: Layers]

Which gives you as you wish; objects each on their own layer now:

[image: Groups to layers]

Hope this helps...

Comment: At the end I found the solution directly in Processing, but this is definitely an answer:)