# Copying Selection to Multiple Layer in Different Position

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, selections, illustrator-scripting, javascript

I am trying to cut selection and paste into four different layers using javascript (layer 01, layer 02 etc.) Like the example picture below:

[image]

I am trying to find a solution but because of my lack of knowledge I failed miserably. Any help is really appreciated. So far I have this code from another post.

```
function test()

{

    var docRef = app.activeDocument;

    var layers = docRef.layers;

    //how many new layers do you want?

    var numLayers = 4;

    var sel = docRef.selection;

    //save the original layer to a variable so we can put it at the bottom of the list

    var originalLayer = layers[0];

    //create new layers

    for(var x=0;x<numLayers;x++)

    {

        var newLay = layers.add();

        //now copy the selection into the newly created layer

        for(var y = sel.length-1;y >-1; y--)

        {

            var thisItem = sel.duplicate(newLay);

        }

    }

    originalLayer.zOrder(ZOrderMethod.SENDTOBACK);

}

test();
```

Comment: Do you need to do this with Javascript? Seems like a bit of a overkill approach. I understand that you likely have to do this 100s of times and want to automate this. But some embedded files that can easily be relinked might be quick enough.

Comment: Yeah that could be a great idea. But I don't have any idea about that. Please let me know the method.

Comment: how many of those do you need to make?

Comment: See duplicate link above. You don't need any script. This is built into Illustrator's Layers Panel.

Comment: I need four copy @julian-steinmann

Comment: @Scott you are a crazy person. My question is not at all related to the suggested question. I need to copy selection to four layers. But not the way suggested in the recommended post. You did a spam in my opinion

Comment: What on earth do you mean? Create 4 copies of the object on a single ayer.. then Release Layers to Sequence.. BAM! you then have 4 layers each with 1 object per layer. Calling me "crazy" and accusing me of "spam" is **certainly** more offensive than my trying to **assist** you.

Comment: I have to do some other task in batch after the task mentioned in my post so your solution is not valid for me. I was angry because without any confirmation and solution my post was closed. I am sorry

Comment: @Scott that may be part of the solution but her main issue as I understand, is to copy and reposition the icons. But anyhow if that only needs to be done to 4 different icons I do not understand why one would need to automate this.

Comment: I have to do the task in over 6,000 icons

Comment: Had a think about this. With scotts suggestions it's easily possible to automate this 'copy, reposition and move icons to separate layers' task without any coding required. Should take only a few minutes to do this for 6000 icons. If you revise the question to be clearer and send scott a friendly message to consider reopening this question he may do so and someone here maybe will explain this in more detail if that's still needed.

Comment: This can **all** be automated in an action... Apply Effect > Distort and Transform > Transform to ONE icon.. To create and reposition 4 copies... Object > Expand ... Layer Panel > Release to Sequence. Done. -- Sorry it's a valid solution if you open your mind a little. I too can sometimes get stuck thinking I need one path for a solution, when there are alternatives possible.

Comment: The question was.. how to move copies to layers, the duplicate link answers that entirely. I do not see how it's not a solution... true it's *not* a script, so I guess that's the issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, fine. I've reopened this. I still think it's merely a duplicate of this question though: [How can I quickly turn all objects of a layer to independent layers in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/35512/how-can-i-quickly-turn-all-objects-of-a-layer-to-independent-layers-in-illustrat)

Please *read* the question.. "how to split objects to layers". The duplicate link answers that question directly. Sure, it's *not* using a script, because you *don't need any scripting*. This entire process can be completed with an **action**.

To be exact....

- `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` to create a copy of an icon
- `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` **again** to create additional copies
- (Added benefit - Make a **Graphic Style** of the art at this point the first time you do this.)
- `Object > Expand Appearance`
- `Object > Ungroup` 3 times (Ungroup once for each copy that was generated - so if you have 5 copies, you'll need to Ungroup 5 times)
- `Layer Panel Menu > Release To Layers (Sequence)`.

There you go... 3 copies of an icon and each one on its own layer.

[image]

This could all be done in an **action** allowing a single press of a hotkey to complete this entire process. You need the **Graphic Style** as previously mentioned. The action won't record the Effect steps, but if you do all that and create a Graphic Style, you can merely apply the style to the artwork via an action.

All the above in a single action, running in real time...

[image]

Comment: I would like to point out that if one wants this to be an action then you can replace the trasform effect with the transform action

Comment: Good point @joojaa - That would make the action itself more transferable, no dependency on the style - and no need for the ungrouping. Style is easy enough to generate though `:)`